# Linking of documents accross site collections

Tags: 2013

I know I can link items to items within the same site collection with a new field type in sharepoint 2013 called related items.

I wonder what are my options if I need to link one documnet in one site collection, with another one in a different site collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SharePoint a special content type exists that is called "Link to a document" and can be added to any document library.

You need first enable management of content types on a library and the you can add it to the library.

Once this has been done you can link to any file based on an http link.

You will find a detailed description of this: [How to use a "Link to a document in place of real document in SharePoint"](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2013/04/03/use-a-link-to-a-document-in-place-of-an-real-document-in-sharepoint#.UnjrfZHDnHM)

Comment: but I want to link an existing document to another document, not put a link in a library to a document

Comment: In this case this is Word related not SharePoint related. You will find a how to here http://www.howtogeek.com/73960/create-a-master-document-in-word-2010-from-multiple-documents/

Comment: that is not correct, not what I want. They want to link documents to documents, so that when they view the properties of a document in sharepoint, they can see the related items (other documents), the problem those documents can in other site collections.

Comment: Then why don't you add a field that says related document. The type of that field should then be rich text field or multiline of text?

Answer (score 1):

You could also set up an external content source to the other SharePoint document list and pull documents in through a list directly that way as well.